# JasperReports Maven broken?

Tags: maven, jasper-reports, sbt

I'm trying to add a dependency to JasperReports to my project (Tried SBT and Maven), but seems one dependency is broken.
I'm using the latest version 6.1.0 from the maven repo (also tested with previous ones and same issue).

I also added the Jasper repository since the itext libs need to be grabbed from there.

But I keep getting these errors:
[info] Resolving org.codehaus.castor#castor-xml;1.3.3 ...
[warn] problem while downloading module descriptor: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/castor/castor-xml/1.3.3/castor-xml-1.3.3.pom: invalid sha1: expected=c9d4075aabdeb9f81ba16455c5dadf2c1f687cb1 computed=a0bc9174f01de7be6d5bdcec580e6a3b999674ec (108ms)
[warn]  module not found: org.codehaus.castor#castor-xml;1.3.3

And:
[info] Resolving org.olap4j#olap4j;0.9.7.309-JS-3 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.olap4j#olap4j;0.9.7.309-JS-3

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.codehaus.castor#castor-xml;1.3.3: not found
[warn]  :: org.olap4j#olap4j;0.9.7.309-JS-3: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Is there any other repository hosting these?

UPDATE: I managed to find the olap dependency at:
https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/artifactory/third-party-ce-artifacts/

Still having problems getting the castor one though.

Comment: I just checked the sha1 form mvncentral `curl http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/castor/castor-xml/1.3.3/castor-xml-1.3.3.pom -s | sha1sum` returns
`a0bc9174f01de7be6d5bdcec580e6a3b999674ec`.

Answer (score 12):

There is a post at the jaspersoft community for this issue:

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/826431/failure-find-orgolap4jolap4jjar097309-js-3

EDIT:

The recommendation is to add additional maven repositories to your configuration, so that the missing artefacts can be found.

As already said this should be https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/artifactory/third-party-ce-artifacts to get olap4j.

I had no problem with the castor-xml artifact at maven-central: [http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.codehaus.castor|castor-xml|1.3.3|jar](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.codehaus.castor%7Ccastor-xml%7C1.3.3%7Cjar)

Answer (score 9):

The answer above worked for us...for a while.  It appears that the provided URL (http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts) is giving 404's now.  The new URL below is our current fix.

`https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/artifactory/third-party-ce-artifacts`

Comment: The `artifactoryonline.com` domain has been deprecated some years ago ([check here](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/deprecation-of-artifactoryonline-com-domain/)). It looks like they decided to drop it this week.

Answer (score 6):

The old third party repository link is broken.
Please set the pluginRepository URL to:

https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/artifactory/third-party-ce-artifacts

```
<pluginRepository>
  <id>jasperreport-artifactory</id>
  <url>https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/artifactory/third-party-ce-artifacts</url>
</pluginRepository>
```

Answer (score 6):

Add this xml in pom.xml

```
   <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>jasperreports</id>
          <url>http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>jaspersoft-third-party</id>
          <url>https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
```

Answer (score 1):

When I exclude some parts of the library it works fine for me:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Add this dependency in pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.olap4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>olap4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency solve my problem